# Where to find PNGs of the native Apple buttons, like detail disclosures, etc?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uikit

I have read in some books that the various graphics that make up UIKit are readily available somewhere in the SDK as individual PNGs, such as the detail disclosure button on UITableViews, and others.

Where do I find these PNGs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open-source project on GitHub which demonstrates how to do this, take a look at it (its not quite trivial, if you are only interested in the graphics, use the demo App to extract what you need)
https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: very cool, thanks. i thought there were other places, but this works just fine.